# accessing sqlite database with each item in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a listview that show some items, each item contains attribute called category Id, this is attribute is related to one of my database taples

I need for each item to open database, make a query to get category object where id = item category id and then show data in the listview

it is very heavy to open database to read record by record

can anyone advice how to solve this problem without opening database many times?

Thanks

Comment: *can anyone advice how to solve this problem without opening database many times?* obviously open it once ... and if it has resonable rows count then use some associative collection(with id as key) for store it ... or if you need only names of categories then use JOIN(eventualy with group_concat)

Answer (score 0):

you can red the data base once. Get all data at the same time. then read the desired data from the returned array.

```
//returns data from DB
String[] array = getInfoDataBase();

//array example

array = ["id1", "name1", "data2","id2", "name2", "data2", ....]

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i = i+3) {
     if (array[i] == //desired id) {
          //get your data from the array like name1, data1
          break; // to stop the fro loop
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOINS` for this purpose.

```
SELECT * FROM item INNER JOIN category ON item.categoryId = category.id WHERE item.id in (id1, id2, id3)
```

You will have to replace `(id1, id2, id3)` with the item Ids in your table.